# Jump links are not working

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

I am using wordpress, and used simple logic for Jump menu links see below:

An example would look like this:

```
<div id="whatever-you-want-to-call-it">
    The content of your div here.
</div>
```

2) Link To Your Anchor Target
To link to your anchor simply use:

```
<a href="#whatever-you-want-to-call-it">Link Text Here</a>
```

or if it's on another page:

```
  <a href="pagename.html#whatever-you-want-to-call-it">Link Text Here</a>
```

but it is not working from another page.For the same page its done, but when I am clicking from another page,it loads only that page not that specific section using id.

Comment: We would need some `code` to be able to help You.

Comment: you have to check the path from href="what-Path-Is-Needed-Here/pagename.html#whatever-you-want-to-call-it" if that is correct it should work

Comment: @Mantosh I have used same logic which I have mentioned in my question.for now you can check my link from above comment

Comment: working as it should be (tested on opera 20 Mac)

Comment: Does the destination load using jquery?

Comment: For everyone the problem is visible if you click on the "+" carefully go to and click on "about" then click on people and you will see the link is right but the page doesn't scroll. so @user3614921 I think the problem is your page trys to scroll to the people section very early where and when it doesn't knows where exactly that element is cause after you load you full-page gallery. so what you could do is: (you have jquery) so try with $(window).load(function(){//alert('everything is loaded'); }); in there you can do a $window.scrollTo() or something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example where you could try.

Save it as a normal test.html on your desktop and open it with your browser.

Then add `#get-me` at the end of the URL and reload the page.

My URL looks like this `file:///Users/ipeak/Desktop/test.html#get-me`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>animate demo</title>
<style>
.big-height {
    width:100%;
    background-color:orange;
    height:1000px;
    margin:20px;
}
#get-me {
    background-color:blue;
    margin:20px;height:500px;
    width:100%;
}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#get-me">click here</a>
    <div class="big-height"></div>
    <div id="get-me"><div>

<script>
$(window).load(function(){

    //alert(window.location.hash);
    $("html,body").animate({
        scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top
    },900);
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What we do here is waiting till the page is loaded. Then via jQuery check the position of the given `hash` element and animate to its position.

Comment: it works only when,alert is there,if I comment that alert it does not working.why?

Comment: @Monica there must be something else, see the example above, alert is not doing anything there cause it's only a comment and it works, make sure the animate function is in $(window).load(){//here});

Comment: can you turn on the console.log(window.location.hash); and add console.log($(window.location.hash).offset().top);

Comment: if I refresh page then it shows specific section,please help me out.

Comment: it just consoles hash value,but doesnt affect on page.not showing section

Comment: add console.log($(window.location.hash).offset().top);

Comment: did you change something? now this works: http://whyness.co.in.previewdns.com/#aq-block-3883-3

Comment: I tried this console.log($(window.location.hash).offset().top); still its not working here.. :(

Comment: if you click on this link: http://whyness.co.in.previewdns.com/#aq-block-3883-3 it will scroll down to the "People" section. in every OSX browser. console.log($(window.location.hash).offset().top); is still not visible but doesn't matter, cause it want change anything except an output in the console

Comment: yes now it's broken again, but before it was working for a while. so I have no idea what you are doing :( kind a hard to say what the problem is... maybe you could clean up your html you have 2x closing `<body>`s..

Comment: why I am unable to see that,on which browser you are looking,I am working on chrome,firefox and safari also.all are showing only home page when i redirect from inner page to homepage.:(

Comment: if I click on this link: http://whyness.co.in.previewdns.com/#aq-block-3883-3 it scroll down to people section. Or I click on the "+" icon, click on about, and then click on people works. Firefox version 29.0.1, safari Version 6.1 (8537.71) (before it worked in chrome). I think the problem is you are loading and doing different things and you have to check when happens what. for the scroll it would be good to be the last thing happening on the page cause all the elements have to be at the right place, img should be loaded if they change heights etc...